# Easy parts for Hilbert class field?

Tags: nt.number-theory

As part of the existence of the Hilbert class field, we have the following equivalence :

Let $k$ be a number field. Then the class group of $k$ is non trivial if and only if $k$ has an abelian extension which is unramified everywhere.

How much of that needs advanced Class Field Theory ? More precisely : 
- is there an easier proof of the fact that if $\mathcal{O}_k$ has a nonprincipal ideal, then $k$ has a nontrivial extension which is unramified everywhere (even just proving this at finite places) ?
- is there an easier way of finding a nonprincipal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ starting from an unramified abelian extension ?

The second question is actually more or less answered as Satz 94 in Hilbert's Zahlbericht. Is there a transparent modern way to see it ? Does that mean that the first question is the hard one and needs all the CFT machinery ?

Comment: If $K$ contains the $n$-th roots of unity and an element of order $n$ in the class group, let $I$ be a non-principal ideal with $I^n = (a)$. Then, adjoining an $n$-th root of $a$ to $K$ gets you an unramified abelian extension.